# Admob Singup/Signin leads to blank page

Tags: android, ads

I'm making an Android app and would like to display ads, and I've been told [AdMob](http://www.google.com/ads/admob/) is the place to be. However, when I try to sign up, I am greeted with a blank page, and if I try to sign in, I'll sign in with my google account, and it tells me to go to a new site if I live in a certain country. Upon visiting that page, I am greeted with another blank screen(https://apps.admob.com/admob/signup). What am I doing wrong? Does anyone else get this? Am I going to the wrong site?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Verify that you are not using an Ad-blocker in your browser (like ABP in Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with Adblock plus and affects Firefox and Chrome.

Simply **disable Adblock plus** and refresh the page.

For more information about this problem I've written an article about it:
http://tpbapp.com/web-development/admob-blank-page-login-register-problem-solved/